# How to remove textbox in runtime?

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a `textbox` named `txtDetailsAdd` and I must remove it if there is no record found in database.How to remove it during runtime. I think there would be two three lines of code.Here  is my code:

But it doesn't work.

```
if ((ShowImage == true) && (dt.Rows[0]["Add_Images"] != null))
{
   //remove textbox and resize image control
   AddTextBox.Visible = false; 
   this.Controls.Remove(AddTextBox); 
   AddImage.ControlStyle.Height = 200;
   AddImage.ControlStyle.Width = 268;
   string img1 = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])(dt.Rows[0]["Add_Images"]));
   AddImage.ImageUrl = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", img1); 
}
```

Comment: Is any error thrown? What's the problem? Is it wpf, windows forms? Say something more.

Comment: It should work just fine. Probably your control is in some kind of container and you should remove it from there. Show some more code if you want help.

Comment: Is `AddTextBox` initialized with new above this if block by any chance?..

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to remove it? Or you just want to hide it?

If you only need to hide the field, you should use the [Visible property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx).

Comment: I agree, it is generally better to hide a control rather than removing it entirely.

Comment: if ((ShowImage == true) && (dt.Rows[0]["Add_Images"] != null))
                    {
                        //remove  textbox and resize image control
                        AddTextBox.Visible = false;
                        this.Controls.Remove(AddTextBox);
                        AddImage.ControlStyle.Height = 200;
                        AddImage.ControlStyle.Width = 268;
                        string img1 = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])(dt.Rows[0]["Add_Images"]));
                        AddImage.ImageUrl = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", img1);
                    }

Comment: I don't want to hide it because if I do not hide it occupies some space in a div.

Comment: @Dee.Pee.Gurung - Please don't paste large sections of code in the comment section as it's hard to read. I've edited it into your main question.

Comment: "I don't want to hide it because if I do not hide it occupies some space in a div" <-- If you hide it, you hide it, am I wrong? :) Hidden element does not take place. Deleting and hiding will do the same if we are talking about space

Comment: if I do not set visible=false then it seems on the page. But its ok if it does not take place. Thankyou for your kind corporation.

Answer (score 2):

Better you can hide it.

```
txtboxName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

This actually won't allocate memory for the textbox which is equivalent to removing.